# Dynamic Data on Facebook Page tab

Tags: facebook, tabs

I am creating an application where any one can sign up and create different things for their account like different newsletters with a url that will show their newsletter content like https://abc.com/newletter?id=1

Suppose there are 2 users having 3 url each. Now I want to give them a functionality that after login to my site they can add their newsletter url on their Facebook pages as Facebook tab.

For this process is as follow:

1. As a super admin I will make a Facebook app and set canvas url, page
   tab url.
2. Now suppose user A come to the link Add on FB and after clicking on
   it , app ask for authentication and after authentication show add
   page tab like http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID
   and user added Facebook tab on their page.

So my question is since each user has 3 newsletters url so I need to create 3 different apps or with a main app it is possible to allow user to add 3 different Facebook tabs on his/her Facebook page.  If possible with a single app then How I will show different content for each news letter in the iframe that  will show their newsletter content.

Comment: An app can only be added to a given page as page tab app once. To have one single app for multiple tabs on the same page is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it is not multiple tabs on the same page. It is single app which can be installed on different pages but I want it show different content according the users who installed it on their pages.

Comment: _“but it is not multiple tabs on the same page”_ – well that’s what you said in your question though. Anyway, to find out what page your app is embedded on, you can read that info from the `signed_request` parameter. (Do some research, this has been discussed before, and is also mentioned in the page tab docs.)